# Program in c with functions without pointers doesn't work

Tags: c, function

I have written a code and it doesn't run. However, there are no mistakes in compiler. I am stuck, could you give me a hint please where am I wrong?
I am 95% sure it is about checktable function.
P.S. I know how to do it with pointers, but I try to understand how to make it without them.

Thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include "genlib.h"

void fillarray (int a[50])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
    a[i]=rand()%10;
}

void printarray (int a[50])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
    printf(" %d ", a[i]);
}

int number()
{
    int num;
    printf("Give the number!");
    num=GetInteger();
    return num;
}

void checktable (int a[50], int b[50], int ar,int count)
{
    int i;
    count=0;
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
    if (a[i]==ar)
    {

        b[count]=i;
        count++;
    }

}
main()
{
    int i,a[50], b[50], N,count;
    fillarray(a);
    printarray(a);
    N=number();
    checktable(a,b,N,count);
    printf("the number is used %d times", count);
    printf("in places:");
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    printf("%d ",b[i]);

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Describe your input, the expected output, and what the difference is.

Comment: This is bad `void fillarray (int a[50])`

Comment: fillarray: fill the table with int (from 1 to 9); printarray: print the previous table; number: user gives a number; checktable: the program counts the times when the chosen number was shown and prints the results (in main, strictly)

Comment: `void checktable (int a[50], int b[50], int ar,int count)`  --> `void checktable (int a[50], int b[50], int ar,int *count)` receive `count` by pointer.

Comment: "it doesn't run" ???

Answer (score 3):

#### Approach 1: The "pointer" way:

In your code, change

`void checktable (int a[50], int b[50], int ar,int count)`

to

`void checktable (int a[50], int b[50], int ar,int *count)`

and call it as `checktable(a,b,N,&count);`

---

#### Approach 2: The "return" way:

Otherwise, the `count` which is updated in `checktable()` won't be reflected in `main()`.

However, Alternatively (without using pointers), IMO, its always *easier* to simply `return` the number of occurrences via `return` statement. In that case , code will look like

```
int checktable (int a[50], int b[50], int ar)
{
    int i;
    int count=0;
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
    if (a[i]==ar)
    {

        b[count]=i;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

and the calling will be

```
 count = checktable(a,b,N);
```

<sup>Note: Its always a good practice to initialize your variables.</sup>

Comment: I totally agree with you, but my exercise has some restrictions to follow

Comment: @Doraemon which restriction? not to use pointers or not to return? Well, in my answer, you have the way-out for both the cases, IMO.

Comment: @CoolGuy A real mistake. Thanks a ton for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use pointers,then you can return `count` and assign it to the `count` variable in `main`. I've improved your code here with all of it explained in the comments inside the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //Don't forget this header for srand and rand
#include <time.h> //For the time in srand
#include <conio.h> //For using getch()
#include "genlib.h"

void fillarray (int a[]) //leave the brackets empty
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
    a[i]=rand()%10;
}

void printarray (int a[]) //here too
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
    printf(" %d ", a[i]);
}

int number()
{
    int num;
    printf("\n\nGive the number!");
    num=GetInteger();
    return num;
}

int checktable (int a[], int b[], int ar) //Use int to return an int
                                          //No need for count parameter
{
    int i,count;
    count=0;
    for(i=0;i<50;i++)
    if (a[i]==ar)
    {
     b[count]=i;
     count++;
    }
    return count;  //returning count

}
int main() //Use int main
{
    int i,a[50], b[50], N,count;
    srand(time(NULL)); //For rand to generate random numbers
    fillarray(a);
    printarray(a);
    N=number();
    count=checktable(a,b,N); //set count to the return value of checktable
                             //Also,no need to pass count as a parameter
    printf("The number is used %d times", count);
    printf(" in places:");
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    printf("%d ",b[i]+1); //Don't forget +1 otherwise output might come as place 0

    getch();
    return 0; //main returns int
}
```